# How to remove the video's thumbnail when it's loaded in JW Player's flash mode?

Tags: javascript, flash, html5-video, jwplayer

I'm trying to implement 'reset'-like functionality for video items loaded with JW Player (5.10).

When the item is displayed first, I store its 'poster' and 'src' attributes in some sort of cache. When 'reset' event handler is called, it retrieves this data - and calls JW Player' JavaScript API `load` method:

```
var contentElement = retrieveCachedData('video', contentId);
// now contentElement looks like this:
// { 
//   file:   '/path/to/videos/video.mp4',
//   image:  '/path/to/images/video_thumbnail.jpg'
// } 
jwplayer(contentId).load(contentElement);
```

It all goes ok when `image` property does exist; the same method is used to `edit` the video, btw. Correct poster and video are displayed both in HTML5 and fallback flash mode.

But somehow things are not so rosy when I try to *delete* the poster image, assigning an empty string to the `image` property of `contentElement` (or dropping this property altogether).

It still works great in the HTML5 mode (when video is stopped, black screen is shown instead of the poster picture). But in the flash mode the existing poster of the video just stays there, as nothing happened.

Does someone have any ideas how to cope with that? I've already thought of feeding some already-made 'blank screen' URL as `image` value. But, frankly, this is ridiculous.

Comment: Upvoted. 50k rep now, congratulations:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `setup` on your player instead of `load`. This seems to do the trick.

In this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jbalsas/RDbvs/1/) you can see how after the video finishes, we force a new setup without the image attribute and the screen removes the older image preview and stays black.

Comment: Well, this is certainly better then loading a custom blank screen image. Have to check it for some side-effects in our case, but looks like a solid solution for now. )

Comment: Happy to help. You could try filing a bug report [here](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/bug-reports). Maybe there's some fix or better workaround. If this is not a bug, at least someone could be able to explain to yo the rationale behind this behavior.